# Meter un array dentro de otro

Tags: javascript, array, json, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente array y quiero hacer un push solo al subitem contenedores para agregar muchos contenedores dentro de él.

```js
let n_data = []
n_data.push({
        booking: datajson.Bookings[0].booking,
        clienteId: datajson.Bookings[0].clienteId,
        clienteRut: datajson.Bookings[0].clienteRut,
        emisionBl: datajson.Bookings[0].emisionBl,
        emisionBlNombre: datajson.Bookings[0].emisionBlNombre,
        consignatario: datajson.Bookings[0].consignatario,
        Contenedores: []
    }

)

for (let i = 0; i < datajson.Bookings.length; i++) {
    n_data.Contenedores.push(numeroContenedor: datajson.Bookings[i].numeroContenedor)
}

console.log(n_data)
```

El código que estoy tratando de hacer tiene sentido para mi pero no me funciona.

Comment: El resultado que esperas es `Contenedores: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`?

Comment: `n_data` no es un `objeto`, es un `array`, por lo tanto debes especificar la posicion del `array` a la que quieres acceder... en vez de `n_data.Contenedores`, debes especificar `n_data[0].Contenedores` (o la posicion que quieras, pero en tu ejemplo solo hay un elemento)